# using asymmetric encryption to encrypt private key

Tags: encryption

Just a small question:
I know it is common for one to use asymmetric encryption in order to encrypt his private key,
when using symmetric encryption.
Is there a name for this process/method of encryption?

Comment: Why would you do a asymmetric encryption of your private key ? Unable to understand your question can u please rephrase

Comment: @Arun: The "private key" up there refers to the symmetric key.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually called hybrid encryption. However, sometimes this is referred to simply by mentioning the asymmetric part - e.g. "encrypting a file with an RSA key" usually means the file will be encrypted with AES or some other symmetric cipher, then the key will be encrypted with RSA.